# Rounding in numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rounding

I have strange problem with python pandas and numpy.

```
>>> np.float64(1) * np.float64(85000) * np.float64(7.543709)
641215.26500000001

>>> round( np.float64(1) * np.float64(85000) * np.float64(7.543709), 2 )
641215.26000000001

>>> np.round( np.float64(1) * np.float64(85000) * np.float64(7.543709), 2 )
641215.26000000001
```

How to round to get correct result 641215.27?

Comment: Simply put, NumPy's `round` function doesn't attempt to do correct rounding. The `round` implementation favours speed over accuracy-at-all-costs, so there are lots of corner cases (like this one) that are *close* to halfway values (but not necessarily exact halfway values) that end up rounding the wrong way.

Answer (score 10):

Numpy's round method favours even numbers, have a look at the abridged numpy source code:

```
def round_(a, decimals=0, out=None):
    return around(a, decimals=decimals, out=out)

def around(a, decimals=0, out=None):
    """
    Evenly round to the given number of decimals.

    Notes
    -----
    For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy
    rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0,
    -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc. Results may also be surprising due
    to the inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE
    floating point standard [1]_ and errors introduced when scaling
    by powers of ten.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> np.around([0.37, 1.64])
    array([ 0.,  2.])
    >>> np.around([0.37, 1.64], decimals=1)
    array([ 0.4,  1.6])
    >>> np.around([.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]) # rounds to nearest even value
    array([ 0.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.])
    >>> np.around([1,2,3,11], decimals=1) # ndarray of ints is returned
    array([ 1,  2,  3, 11])
    >>> np.around([1,2,3,11], decimals=-1)
    array([ 0,  0,  0, 10])

    """
```

#### Example:

If you need to print the string you can format it to give you the right answer:

```
import numpy as np

num = np.float64(1) * np.float64(85000) * np.float64(7.543709)
print(num)
print(float("{0:.2f}".format(num)))
print(np.round(num, 2))
print()

num += 0.02
print(num)
print(float("{0:.2f}".format(num)))
print(np.round(num, 2))
```

gives you

```
641215.265
641215.27
641215.26

641215.285
641215.29
641215.28
```

Comment: Wow, this is surprising.  Good answer!  I assumed the issue would be that there was an underlying value like `.49999` showing as `.50000` but that is not the case.

Comment: @JohnE: Right, this should round up, even under round-ties-to-even. It's the "errors introduced when scaling by powers of ten" part of the docstring that's relevant here.

Comment: @MarkDickinson  OK, thanks.  I guess in a nutshell this is just an example that with floating point you think of numbers like `.5` as just being approximately `.5` and could go up or down, and if you don't like that then you shouldn't be using floating point!  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you can't use `round( float(num), 2 )` when you work with dataframes:

for examle: `df.first * df.second * df.third`
How to round in that case?
You can't make `float(dt.first)`?

This is one solution: `df.first.apply(lambda x: round(float(x), 2))`
But I think is not fast...