# round() function behaves differently in apply() function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda, rounding

I grabbed a row from a dataframe which is like the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9LUE.png

or

```
Clicks  Spend   clk_ar  CPC     AdRank  temp    tempRan
36.0    248.76  59.94   6.91    1.67    1.665   1.67
```

I need to round values with 2 digits in column `temp`

Option 1:

```
round(df.temp,2)

OUTPUT:
1676725    1.66
Name: temp, dtype: float64
```

Option 2:

```
df.temp.apply(lambda x:round(x,2))

OUTPUT:
1676725    1.67
Name: temp, dtype: float64
```

The two round functions show different behaviors. Obviously option 1 is aligned with python 3 behavior. See [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)

I am just wondering why option 2 behaves like that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813777/rounding-in-numpy/42814054).

Comment: The bit that surprises me slightly is that pulling values out of a Pandas `Series` with dtype `np.float64` gives actual Python `float` objects rather than NumPy `float64` objects. (The two round differently on Python 3 even under Python's built-in `round` function.)

Comment: Except that if you pull the values out _directly_ via indexing, you _do_ get `np.float64` instances instead of `float` instances. It's only under `apply` that you mysteriously get regular `float`s. Gah!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason is here per [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around)

> Notes
>
> For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy
>   rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5
>   and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc. Results may also be surprising due to the
>   inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE floating point
>   standard [1] and errors introduced when scaling by powers of ten.

In Option 1, you are rounding numpy.float which is using the about rules.

In Option 2, you are rounding a python float data type [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round).

Fun with floating point arithmetic:

```
round(1.675, 2)  
1.68

round(2.675, 2) 
2.67
```

Comment: It's more subtle than this. In fact, Python's `round` follows the nearest-ties-to-even rule in all cases, while NumPy's does not. But because of the usual What You See Is Not What You Get nature of binary floating-point, the value actually being rounded isn't a halfway case at all. On a typical machine, the actual value being rounded will be `1.66500000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625`, which should round up.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you for this information and insight.

Comment: Yes, sorry; I'm being unnecessarily nitpicky; the difference is, exactly as you state, that we're rounding NumPy `float64` instances versus regular Python `float`s, though it's a bit of a mystery why we're getting regular Python `float`s out of a `Series` with dtype `np.float64`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson No need to apologize, I value such insights.  Thanks again.