# Why is there a difference between round(x) and round(np.float64(x))?

Tags: python, numpy

From what i understand, 2.675 and numpy.float64(2.675) are both the same number. However, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67, while round(np.float64(2.675), 2) gives 2.68. Why does this happen?

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

x = 2.675
np_x = np.float64(x)
type(x) # float
Decimal(x)    # Decimal('2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
Decimal(np_x) # Decimal('2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
x == np_x # True

# This is the bit that bothers me
round(x, 2) # 2.67
round(np_x, 2) # 2.68

# Using numpy's round gives 2.68 for both the numpy float as well as the Python built-in float...
np.round(x, 2) # 2.68
np.round(np_x, 2) # 2.68

# ... but this is because it might be converting the number to a numpy float before rounding
type(np.round(x, 2)) # numpy.float64

# Versions
# Python 3.6.8 running on 64-bit Windows 10
# Numpy 1.16.2
```

Comment: Perhaps this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813777/rounding-in-numpy/42814054

Comment: Thanks, Devesh. Still not clear on the difference in results between Python float 2.675 and np.float64(2.765). The page you linked to makes the excellent point that numpy's round() implementation favours speed over accuracy - but am curious about why it gets different results due to different data types.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question :)
Looks like it has to do with numbers that end with a 5.
Numpy rounds them by excess, but not always...

```
# list of incoherences between Python Numpy with round(x, 2)
for i in range(1001):
    x = i/1000
    np_x = np.float64(x)
    if round(x, 2) != round(np_x, 2):
        print(x)

# 0.005
# 0.015
# 0.025   <<< some values are missing!
# 0.065
# 0.075
# 0.085
# ...
```

Comment: I doubt using == or != is a good idea on floats. numpy has a isclose() method.

Comment: Thomas Weller if you watch closely I'm using != on rounded number, so there's no problem what so ever :)